# Crop A4 to specific paper size

Tags: koma-script, dimensions, crop

I want to send a document to a publisher. The publisher prints books with the dimensions of the pages being 16.5cm x 23.5cm. Thus I am now layouting the final document with the help of the crop package. I am trying to tell KOMA Script & crop that the resulting PDF needs to be DIN A4 (physical page) with the 16.5cm x 23.5cm page centered on the physical page. Crop gives my crop marks and (using the option "frame") a thin, black frame which is very useful during the final layouting process.

But the problem is that the dimensions of the framed page resp. the dimensions of the page enclosed by the crop marks are not what I am trying to specify (16.5cm x 23.5cm). It's smaller, actually something like 16cm x 22.9cm.

Why is that -- I guess I am doing something wrong? Is this maybe related to this 'bleed correction' which I have stumbled across at some point?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[paper=16.5cm:23.5cm,11pt,BCOR=5mm,twoside,DIV=12]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4,center,cam]{crop}
% Needed?
\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

What's the correct way to specify such non-standard dimensions precisely? In case this is important, I am using KOMA Script (scrreprt).

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you measuring this? Note that issues like this often stem from PDF viewers shrinking the contents prior to printing it.

Comment: I print out the PDF on A4 paper and measure with a state of the art measuring device: a ruler!
Once I have printed the file with 'lp' and once with evince, the result is the same.

Comment: You still need to verify that what you print actually corresponds to the correct sizes. Is a printed `\rule{6cm}{2cm}` actually `6cm` by `2cm`?

Comment: Wow. I did not expect this. According to measurements on paper the box is not 6cm x 2cm, but rather 5.8cm x 1.95cm.

This roughly agrees with the scaling factor of post:
6/5.8 is approx. 1.034 and 16.5/16 is approx 1.031
2/1.95 is approx 1.025 and 23.5/23 is approx 1.021

This is strange. I didn't know that there is such a scaling involved in printing PDF A4.

Comment: In evince (and adobe reader) remember to set `page scaling` to `none`, then this does not happen. I have no idea why they scale the page when they do not need to.

Comment: @mfuglos If you print with Adobe, you have to select an option named 'real size' or similar - I only see it in German on my system as 'Tatsächliche Größe'.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm, that can be quite dangerous. It seems that AR then sends the size as x points by y points instead of telling the printer to use A4. Thus many printers see this as custom paper size and will ask for this particular type of paper even if that sizer is equal to A4. We have several of thse printers. It is a nightmare.

Comment: @daleif Yes, I know this problem from our printers. If the printer just holds one type of paper, deselecting the paper source selection check box helps ('Papierquelle gemäß PDF-Seitengröße auswählen' on my system). But for printer holding A4 and A3, this is obviously no good idea.

Answer (score 2):

This was in fact not a TeX problem, but merely a printing problem. I have found the appropriate printing settings so that the page does not get scaled down (by a factor approx. being 0,97) to fit into the printable area of the printer, but the printable area gets cut out from the PDF. Thanks!